# Linux detects only 4 of my 6 SATA drives

Tags: linux, sata, ahci

The issue I'm having is that only the first 4 of my 6 drives are showing up - sda through sdd. No sde+sdf in udev, no sde+sdf in /sys/block.

I have an MSI 760GM-P23FX motherboard, and as near as I can tell it handles all 6 SATA ports through the SB710 southbridge. All 6 are colored the same, and from the manual it seems there should be no differences between them. Furthermore, on POST the bios detects all 6 drives.

I'm running a custom-compiled 2.6.39.4 (gotten direct from kernel.org). I'd assume I missed a config option, except it's finding the first 4 drives just fine. Is the kernel's SFF support limited to 4 drives or something?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be, "Yes, Linux only supports the first 4 drives in SFF/legacy IDE mode." When I switched the BIOS to AHCI, everything just worked.